# Definition of Solvable by Radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am currently trying to understand the definition of solvability by radicals. In the definition he takes a polynomial $f(x)$ over the field $K$ and then considers its splitting field $L$ and requires $L$ to be subfield of a radical extension.

The part I do not understand is why is he taking the splitting field why not just just adjoin a root say $\zeta$ and require that $K(\zeta)$ be contained in a radical extension. Clearly the first definition implies the second but I am not sure if second implies the first. Thank You.

Comment: To solve a polynomial would be to factor it.  To factor it, you need all the roots to exist in the field.  So, he wants all the roots to be contained in a subfield of a radical extension for the polynomial to be solvable.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 but what is wrong if just one root can be written as radicals

Comment: The problem would be something like a polynomial with roots $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$.  Then $\sqrt{2}$ is in a radical extension, but $\pi$ is not.  So, we wouldn't want such a polynomial to be "solvable by radicals".

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I am sorry I do not understand but isn't the polynomial with the above two roots a quadratic and hence solvable by radicals

Comment: It is quadratic, but is not a polynomial from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: The claim that all quadratics are solvable by radicals only applies to polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 thanks for clarifying I did not know that